# From 256bit randomize from array of 54 elements

Tags: random, probability

If I have a 256 bit array (selector),Ho do I select 5 elements from an array of 54 element using the 256 bit array ?. It's possible to take only first K bits from selector array to accomplish it and not use all the 256 bit.
The requirements are:

- Same selector will lead to same 5 elements being picked .
- Need it to be statistically fair so if I run all every possibility of bits in
  the selector array it will bring an even spread of times occurrences
  in the the 5 elements array.

I know that there is 2,598,960 combinations of 5 element can be selected from array of 54, without caring about the order of selecting them.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with whatever it is you're trying to do. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB edited to a question.

Comment: Great question. Upvoting to cancel idiotic downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick one of 54, one of 53, ... one of 50. Take the random bits 6 at a time as numbers from 1..64.  Simply discard any that are too big (more than 54, 53, or whatever). On the average, you'll need six or seven tries to get your 5 random numbers. You have 42 available, so there's no chance you'll run out, and your distribution will be perfectly uniform.

Comment: Why to you jump 2 steps in picking ? "one of 54, one of 52, ... one of 50"

Comment: I can't take random, I don't want to use random. The given 256 bit is the random representation.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, just taking them 6 bits at a time. Just make sure you pick the bits the same way, and the same input will always produce the same output.

Comment: There could be possibility where I have a 256 bit from right to left 000011000011000011000011000011 ... and so on , I can't find element in the array cause all are larger then 54

Comment: You have 256 random bits. That's 42 groups of 6. The odds of you running out are about 2 in 10**24. If you did this a million times a second, you'd have a problem every 63 trillion years or so. If you're really worried about that, add code that sets a particular order when that happens...it will still be so close to statistically perfect that no possible program could tell the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74146/discussion-between-haddar-macdasi-and-lee-daniel-crocker).

Comment: I don't chat, it's a waste of time. Everything I have to say is here on the record. Use it if you like, or don't, that's up to you.

Comment: how did you calculate the probability 2 in 10**24 ?

Comment: The probability of any one 6-bit number being over 54 is about 22%. You need 36 failures. .22 to the 36th is about 2 in 10**24.

Comment: I think there is more probability for having equal number of 1 and 0 in a 6 bit array. so after taking 6 bits each time it is less likely to have a representation of 000001 then of 101010, am I right ? having said that it means my random is less likely to select smaller number from the fist deck

Comment: Not if your bits are truly random. Six random bits are exactly as likely to be 101010 as 000000 or 111111--that's what random means. If your bits aren't random, all bets are off. Also, I know my calculation isn't exact (36-out-of-42 failures is more likely than 36-in-a-row), but it's in the same ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if 2^K is larger than 2.598,960* you can use K bits to select 5 elements. You won't get an entirely uniform distribution because no power of 2 is divisible by 2,598,960.

<sub>*I did not check your math, I just assume 2,598,960 is correct</sub>